# Guide or any tool to convert FetchXML to SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I have below FetchXML query used to create report in Business Intelligent Development Studio.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="incident">
    <attribute name="ticketnumber" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <attribute name="statuscode" />
    <attribute name="incidentid" />
    <attribute name="caseorigincode" />
    <attribute name="new_statussla" />
    <attribute name="ownerid" />
    <attribute name="new_caseaging" />
    <attribute name="casetypecode" />
    <order attribute="ticketnumber" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
<condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="@Startdate" />
    <condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-before" value="@Enddate" />
    <condition attribute="caseorigincode" operator="ne" value="3" />
</filter>
<link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="owninguser" visible="false" link-type="outer" alias="a_cf39b8fda77b421483a1af5e511c39ca">
  <attribute name="new_region" />
  <attribute name="businessunitid" />
</link-entity>
 </entity>
</fetch>
```

I do converting this query to SQL query like below.

```
SELECT a.ticketnumber, a.createdon, a.statuscode,
a.incidentid, a.caseorigincode, a.new_statussla,
a.ownerid, a.new_caseaging, a.casetypecode,
b.new_region, b.businessunitid
FROM FilteredIncident a, FilteredSystemUser b
WHERE a.ownerid = b.systemuserid
AND createdon >= @StartDate
AND creaedon <= @EndDate
AND caseorigincode != '3'
```

My Question, is my SQL Query correct ? Eventhough I can execute it.

Comment: Mr. Shaa there is no tool to convert xml to sql , you do this manually where you will make a parser ...

Comment: you can try this, https://fetchxml2sql.codeplex.com/ or you can extract it from SQL Profiler...

Comment: Side note: Please avoid using old-style joins. explicit joins are a part of ansi-sql for more then 20 years now. for more information, [read this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Ok thanks, mr @ZoharPeled can u show me the example using the above query. Can contact me shaaruddin.daud@mason.com.my.

Comment: I have no answer to your question. If I had one, I would post it here and not write you an email about it.

Comment: I think what you wrote looks accurate, at least, that's how I'd write it.

Answer (score 2):

Well out of need I just created this. [FetchXML to SQL Convertor](https://github.com/abtevrythng/FetchXML-to-SQL) free on GitHub!

A work in progress, but will give a usable output. Do Try! https://github.com/abtevrythng/FetchXML-to-SQL

here is the generated output for your fetchXML:

```
SELECT incident.ticketnumber, incident.createdon, incident.statuscode, incident.incidentid, incident.caseorigincode, incident.new_statussla, incident.ownerid, incident.new_caseaging, incident.casetypecode, systemuser.new_region, systemuser.businessunitid 
FROM incident 
LEFT OUTER JOIN systemuser ON incident.systemuserid = systemuser.owninguser
WHERE incident.createdon TBD '@Startdate'  AND incident.createdon TBD '@Enddate'  AND incident.caseorigincode != '3'
```